# Insert into table via UDF table not working from stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

My stored procedure should insert data into table via UDF.

The string I generate is correct when I run it as SQL statement, but when I execute it through the stored procedure, it throws a syntax error.

This is the SQL statement:

```
insert into dbname.public.TBLPROVIDER 
    select * 
    from table(f_TBLPROVIDER('dbname',cast('20211031233226' as bigint)));
```

Here is the code which is failing from the stored procedure

```
var sql_tbl_populate  = "insert into " + S_DB_NAME + ".public." + TBL_NAME + " "
sql_tbl_populate += "select * from table(f_" + TBL_NAME +"('"+ S_DB_NAME + "',cast('" + S_TIMESTAMP + "' as bigint)));"
stmt_sql_tbl_populate = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: sql_tbl_populate} );
stmt_sql_tbl_populate.execute();
```

The error is

> Execution error in stored procedure SP_POPULATE_TRGT_TABLES: SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1 at position 105 unexpected 'dbname'.
> At Statement.execute, line 21 position 23

Comment: Please check the SQL history to see what exact command is being generated from the code used in SP.
A sample for this would as follows:

 var sql_tbl_populate = snowflake.createStatement({
         sqlText: "INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES('" + TABLE_NAME + "','" + cols[i] + "')" + ";"
              });

Comment: Can you add the whole body of the procedure to the question?

Comment: One way to debug stored procedures like this is to return the SQL statement from the procedure before executing it, eg. return sql_tbl_populate from the procedure before calling snowflake.createStatement and comment out everything after this statement.

Answer (score -2):

I am able to locate your query and find out the DDL of your SP.

The issue lies on the below query when you tried to insert into the tbl_log table:

```
var sqld = "insert into log_table values ('" + sql_tbl_populate + "')";
```

The actually failed query was:

```
insert into log_table values ('insert into dbname.public.tablename select * from table(f_TBLPROVIDER('dbname',cast('20211031233226' as bigint)));')
```

Because you had single quotes around the variable "sql_tbl_populate", which already had the single quote for the parameters in the function f_TBLPROVIDER.

You need to escape the single quotes inside "sql_tbl_populate" when you build your INSERT statement in variable "sqld".